# Ubuntu mysql database doesnot recognise spanish accent characters

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, utf-8, php-5.3

I have a problem with storing spanish text in mysql database in Ubuntu.
The spanish accent characters like ñ are displayed incorrectly as "Ã±"
This happens in production not in development environment.

I know that this is not a mysql database issue. Since both development and production databases are exactly same and are utf8-mb4 enabled.

Development environment - Windows, PHP 6.0 and Mysql 5.6.14
Production environment - Ubuntu, PHP 5.3.2 and Mysql 5.6.14-62.0

All the php files in dev and production are UTF-8 without BOM encoded

Any recommendations of how to fix this issue?
Would upgrading php version help?

Comment: Afaik **there is no such thing as PHP 6.0** (jet). PHP 5.5 is the latest. Also why don't you match your development environment to the production one? There is nothing worse than using a function only to realise that it's only available in a higher PHP version than the production one - just because it was available during development.

Comment: PHP 6.0 is available. its just not a stable version. Hence we have not implemented in production. That's the last resort. But any other recommendations?

Comment: 5.6 is the latest snapshot. You must have got your PHP from the black market :p

Comment: I don't know if Appserv is considered black market :P here is the link where i got PHP 6.0 from http://www.appservnetwork.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=46 Anyway i figured out the problem is with the mysql client. :P The database has the right characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting two bytes back it looks like, which is good. If this is being displayed on a web page, are the headers being set correctly? What does the browser say it's interpreting the results as?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely culprit in this case is that the php<->mysql connection isn't set to be `utf8`. See the connection "Configuring the MySQL Connection" in http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/

The exact syntax will depend on how you connect to Mysql.

Comment: PHP MySQL connection is set to UTF-8 for both dev and production. As I mentioned, the code works perfectly on Dev. Only in production the characters are not recognized.

Comment: In that case, I would go with the other stack overflow answer and check if the letters are displayed correctly if, on the browser, you manually change the the encoding to utf-8 (Menu->Tools->Encoding in chrome). If that works, try the suggestions under "Making sure that web browsers know to use UTF-8" in that same article.